# AppDelegate.h errors suddenly appear

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, appdelegate

I have not touched the AppDelegate.h file all day and suddenly I am getting 3 errors...

```
//  AppDelegate.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>  //!Expected selector for Objective-C method
                         //!Expected method body

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;  //!Unknown type name "ViewController" did you mean "UIViewController?

@end
```

I put the errors in the above code as comments.

I see that others have had similar errors in the past but I do not see an answers that make sene in my situation.

My root UIViewController is named ViewController. What did I do to cause these errors to suddenly appear? All I did today was add a new ViewControler and xib to use in a UIPopoverController. I had just gotten the popover to work properly and this started happening.

John

Comment: Post the code of the files that `#import` that file.  Just lines before the import are important, not the whole file.

Comment: So simple!!!! main.m had a + character inserted before the // on the first line. Please post an answer so I can give you credit. Trying to think how I could have accidently put it there. I never go to the main.m file and if I had why would I have hit the + key.

Comment: Ok done. I would imagine you simply knocked a key accidentally - I've done it many times before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've introduced a syntax error in the lines of the source file that `#import`s that header file.